# Kubernetes - PersistentVolumeClaim failed

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a GKE based Kubernetes setup and a POD that requires a storage volume. I attempt to use the config below:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-scratch-space
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
resources:
  requests:
    storage: 2000Gi
storageClassName: standard
```

This PVC is not provisioned. I get the below error:

```
Failed to provision volume with StorageClass "standard": googleapi: Error 503: The zone 'projects/p01/zones/europe-west2-b' does not have enough resources available to fulfill the request.  Try a different zone, or try again later.
```

Looking at GKE quotas page, I don't see any issues. Deleting other PVCs also is not solving the issue. Can anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no configuration problem at your side - there are actually not enough resources in the `europe-west2-b` zone to create a 2T persistent disk. Either try for a smaller volume or use a different zone.

There is an [example for GCE](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#gce) in the docs. Create a new StorageClass specifying say the `europe-west1-b` zone (which is actually cheaper than `europe-west2-b`) like this:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: gce-pd-europe-west1-b
provisioner: kubernetes.io/gce-pd
parameters:
  type: pd-standard
  zones: europe-west1-b
```

And modify your PVC:

```
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: my-scratch-space
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
resources:
  requests:
    storage: 2000Gi
storageClassName: gce-pd-europe-west1-b
```

Comment: a smaller 1TB PVC worked ok and I chose the SSD type as well  :) thanks